# Splitting 'contenteditable' article into vertical pages with header and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am working on a basic WYSIWYG word processor dealing with lengthy documents. Currently I am taking a HTML `article` element filled with approximately 5000 `divs` and applying some jQuery code to style and format it. 5000 is likely to be the absolute maximum.

- Firstly, I use regex to apply CSS and this is working nicely at about
  `107ms`.
- Secondly, I iterate over the divs, storing their height and
  every `1000px`, inserting some HTML to act as a page break (the
  pagination is vertical - imagine pages in MS Word). The second part
  takes around `1200ms`.

For initial page loading, I'm okay with that. Unfortunately, the `article` element needs to be `contenteditable`.

When a user changes the content of the article, I can simply apply my regex on the div they have changed (`0-1ms`) and that is no problem, however, any change to the content means (a possible) altering of the height between page breaks, and therefore necessitates repagination.

Having the browser lock up for a second every time the user hits `return`, `delete`, ends up on a new line or numerous other additional events that would alter the pagination is obviously not practical. While performance is better when making changes nearer the end of document, the user requires the same level of responsiveness when making changes to page one.

I need to address this performance issue and make the UI responsive when repaginating.

Here's an example of the HTML before the JS code is run on it:

```
<article contenteditable="true">
    <header contenteditable="false"><h1>Header Text</h1></header>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    ...
    <footer contenteditable="false"><h3>Footer Text</h3></footer>
</article>
```

And after the JS code is run:

```
<article contenteditable="true">
    <header contenteditable="false"><h1>Header Text</h1></header>
    <div class="regex-set-class">Content</div>
    <div class="regex-set-class">Content</div>
    <div class="regex-set-class">Content</div>
    <section contenteditable="false">
        <h3>Footer Text</h3>
        <figure><hr><hr></figure>
        <h1>Header Text</h1>
        <h2>Page Number</h2>
    </section>
    <div class="regex-set-class">Content</div>
    <div class="regex-set-class">Content</div>
    <div class="regex-set-class">Content</div>
    ...
    <footer contenteditable="false"><h3>Footer Text</h3></footer>
</article>
```

And here is the JS code performing the pagination:

```
function PaginateDocument()
{
    // Variables
    var height = 0;
    var page_count = 1; 

    // Remove existing page breaks
    $("section").remove();

    // Iterate over each div elements
    $("div").each(function()
    {
        // Check whether page is too long
        if (height + $(this).outerHeight(true) > 1000) 
        {
            // Create page break
            $(this).before("<section contenteditable=\"false\"><h3>" + page_footer + "</h3><figure><hr /><hr /></figure><h1>" + page_header + "</h1><h2>" + page_count + ".</h2></section>");            

            // Adjust variables
            page_count++; height = 0;
        }

        // Increment current page height
        height += $(this).outerHeight(true);
    });
}
```

Comment: I know this post is quite old but I would think that only having `$(this).outerHeight(true)` once per iteration would help the performance. It still won't be perfect but it's a start.